# Next js with dynamic routing ([[…slug.js]]) to handle all URLs show 404 for links to home page - but only when deployed

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-link

I want a single dynamic route to handle all requests in this application, so I have written a file named `[[...slug]].js` to do so. I use `getServerSideProps()` for data loading, so it is server-side rendered, generally. I don't have any `index.js` files.

When it runs locally in development mode it works perfectly fine. When deployed (to Vercel) everything keeps working *except* links to `/`. `<Link href={"/"}>…` will request an index.json file from the server, get a 404 response and show error page. Why?

Comment: `passHref` does fix the problem but leaves me even more confused. The Link contains A tag which contains just text. My impression is that this should work out-of-the-box and is not the type of code that would require passHref..
Deployment:
https://studio-ship.vercel.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha!

I use `getServerSideProps()` to fetch data depending on the slug. (Actual content is from Sanity.io and is queried to see if the content's `slug` property matches either `slug` from the URL or a default page slug).

When running the app in local development mode with `next dev`, the `params.slug` argument will be `undefined` when loading the root ("/") URL. It has the same value whether the root URL is loaded by a refresh or a navigation action (clicking a link to /, using back button).

However, when the site is deployed, this behaviour changes. `params.slug` is still `undefined` when the page is first loaded, but if it loads in response to a client-side navigation event the slug is suddenly set to `index`. Since I neither had a page with slug `index` nor ensured we used the default slug when `index` was requested, I got unexpected 404 responses. Using `"index"` as one of the values that triggers the default slug fixes it.

I don't know if it is a bug in Next JS, but it was definitely a gotcha that confused me for a while.